# How to display wide table with specific order (month year) even when data points are missing?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data, longtable, yearmonth

```
    > df_1
    # A tibble: 47 x 3
    # Groups:   therapy_class [9]
       therapy_class             Year_month count
       <ord>                     <yearmon>  <int>
     1 ALK Inhibitors            Dec 2019      16
     2 ALK Inhibitors            Jan 2020      14
     3 ALK Inhibitors            Feb 2020      14
     4 ALK Inhibitors            Mar 2020      22
     5 ALK Inhibitors            Apr 2020      13
     6 ALK Inhibitors            May 2020      17
     7 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Dec 2019      33
     8 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Jan 2020      35
     9 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Feb 2020      36
    10 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Mar 2020      20
    # … with 37 more rows



    A tibble: 10 x 7
       therapy_class                    `Dec 2019`         `Jan 2020`         `Feb 2020`        `Mar 2020`        `Apr 2020`        `May 2020`       
       <ord>                            <chr>              <chr>              <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            
     1 ALK Inhibitors                   "16 <br>[2.7%]"    "14 <br>[2.0%]"    "14 <br>[2.2%]"   "22 <br>[3.3%]"   "13 <br>[2.1%]"   "17 <br>[3.4%]"  
     2 Anti-VEGF-based therapies        "33 <br>[5.6%]"    "35 <br>[4.9%]"    "36 <br>[5.7%]"   "20 <br>[3.0%]"   "21 <br>[3.4%]"   "20 <br>[4.0%]"  
     3 EGFR TKIs                        "52 <br>[8.8%]"    "57 <br>[8.0%]"    "60 <br>[9.5%]"   "52 <br>[7.8%]"   "56 <br>[9.2%]"   "49 <br>[9.8%]"  
     4 EGFR-antibody based therapies    ""                 ""                 ""                ""                ""                ""               
     5 Non-platinum-based chemotherapy… "1 <br>[0.2%]"     "4 <br>[0.6%]"     "4 <br>[0.6%]"    ""                "1 <br>[0.2%]"    ""               
     6 IO-based therapies               "308 <br>[52.0%]"  "385 <br>[54.0%]"  "330 <br>[52.3%]" "379 <br>[56.7%]" "345 <br>[56.4%]" "265 <br>[52.9%]"
     7 Platinum-based chemotherapy com… "123 <br>[20.8%]"  "147 <br>[20.6%]"  "128 <br>[20.3%]" "134 <br>[20.1%]" "120 <br>[19.6%]" "107 <br>[21.4%]"
     8 Single agent chemotherapies      "29 <br>[4.9%]"    "33 <br>[4.6%]"    "17 <br>[2.7%]"   "28 <br>[4.2%]"   "25 <br>[4.1%]"   "22 <br>[4.4%]"  
     9 Other                            "30 <br>[5.1%]"    "38 <br>[5.3%]"    "42 <br>[6.7%]"   "33 <br>[4.9%]"   "31 <br>[5.1%]"   "21 <br>[4.2%]"  
    10 <strong>Total</strong>           "<strong>592</str… "<strong>713</str… "<strong>631</st… "<strong>668</st… "<strong>612</st… "<strong>501</st…


    > df_2
    # A tibble: 46 x 3
    # Groups:   therapy_class [9]
       therapy_class             Year_month count
       <ord>                     <yearmon>  <int>
     1 ALK Inhibitors            Dec 2019      16
     2 ALK Inhibitors            Feb 2020      14
     3 ALK Inhibitors            Mar 2020      22
     4 ALK Inhibitors            Apr 2020      13
     5 ALK Inhibitors            May 2020      17
     6 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Dec 2019      33
     7 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Jan 2020      35
     8 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Feb 2020      36
     9 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Mar 2020      20
    10 Anti-VEGF-based therapies Apr 2020      21
    # … with 36 more rows

> t2
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   therapy_class                    `Dec 2019`         `Feb 2020`         `Mar 2020`        `Apr 2020`        `May 2020`        `Jan 2020`       
   <ord>                            <chr>              <chr>              <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            
 1 ALK Inhibitors                   "16 <br>[2.7%]"    "14 <br>[2.2%]"    "22 <br>[3.3%]"   "13 <br>[2.1%]"   "17 <br>[3.4%]"   ""               
 2 Anti-VEGF-based therapies        "33 <br>[5.6%]"    "36 <br>[5.7%]"    "20 <br>[3.0%]"   "21 <br>[3.4%]"   "20 <br>[4.0%]"   "35 <br>[5.0%]"  
 3 EGFR TKIs                        "52 <br>[8.8%]"    "60 <br>[9.5%]"    "52 <br>[7.8%]"   "56 <br>[9.2%]"   "49 <br>[9.8%]"   "57 <br>[8.2%]"  
 4 EGFR-antibody based therapies    ""                 ""                 ""                ""                ""                ""               
 5 Non-platinum-based chemotherapy… "1 <br>[0.2%]"     "4 <br>[0.6%]"     ""                "1 <br>[0.2%]"    ""                "4 <br>[0.6%]"   
 6 IO-based therapies               "308 <br>[52.0%]"  "330 <br>[52.3%]"  "379 <br>[56.7%]" "345 <br>[56.4%]" "265 <br>[52.9%]" "385 <br>[55.1%]"
 7 Platinum-based chemotherapy com… "123 <br>[20.8%]"  "128 <br>[20.3%]"  "134 <br>[20.1%]" "120 <br>[19.6%]" "107 <br>[21.4%]" "147 <br>[21.0%]"
 8 Single agent chemotherapies      "29 <br>[4.9%]"    "17 <br>[2.7%]"    "28 <br>[4.2%]"   "25 <br>[4.1%]"   "22 <br>[4.4%]"   "33 <br>[4.7%]"  
 9 Other                            "30 <br>[5.1%]"    "42 <br>[6.7%]"    "33 <br>[4.9%]"   "31 <br>[5.1%]"   "21 <br>[4.2%]"   "38 <br>[5.4%]"  
10 <strong>Total</strong>           "<strong>592</str… "<strong>631</str… "<strong>668</st… "<strong>612</st… "<strong>501</st… "<strong>699</st…
>
```

I am trying to create a wide table with counts and percentages from long table. The columns are 'Month Year' which needs to be in order. My issue is when there are rows missing for certain 'Month Year' for the first group (ALK Inhibitors) then the order of the column is disrupted. The missing 'Month Year' is place at the end. Also the long table is not a fixed table. It is generated from function where user gets to choose the month year range. So Year_month column could have any range.

In this example I used Dec 2019 to May 2020 6 month range. "df_1" has all 6 month so the resulting wide table is as expected. "df_2" has Jan 2020 missing for ALK Inhibitors. So the resulting table has 'Jan 2020' at the end.

This is the code I am using the generate the wide table:

```
df_2 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("20")), list(
    ~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", paste(., sprintf("<br>[%1.1f%%]", 100 * (. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))))
  ))
```

Here is the sample data df_2

```
structure(list(therapy_class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("ALK Inhibitors", 
"Anti-VEGF-based therapies", "EGFR TKIs", "EGFR-antibody based therapies", 
"Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "IO-based therapies", 
"Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "Single agent chemotherapies", 
"Other"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Year_month = structure(c(2019.91666666667, 
2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 2020.25, 2020.33333333333, 
2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 2020.25, 
2020.33333333333, 2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 
2020.25, 2020.33333333333, NA, 2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 
2020.25, 2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 
2020.25, 2020.33333333333, 2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 
2020.16666666667, 2020.25, 2020.33333333333, 2019.91666666667, 
2020, 2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 2020.25, 2020.33333333333, 
2019.91666666667, 2020, 2020.08333333333, 2020.16666666667, 2020.25, 
2020.33333333333), class = "yearmon"), count = c(16L, 14L, 22L, 
13L, 17L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 52L, 57L, 60L, 52L, 56L, 
49L, NA, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 308L, 385L, 330L, 379L, 345L, 265L, 
123L, 147L, 128L, 134L, 120L, 107L, 29L, 33L, 17L, 28L, 25L, 
22L, 30L, 38L, 42L, 33L, 31L, 21L)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), groups = structure(list(
    therapy_class = structure(1:9, .Label = c("ALK Inhibitors", 
    "Anti-VEGF-based therapies", "EGFR TKIs", "EGFR-antibody based therapies", 
    "Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "IO-based therapies", 
    "Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "Single agent chemotherapies", 
    "Other"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = structure(list(
        1:5, 6:11, 12:17, 18L, 19:22, 23:28, 29:34, 35:40, 41:46), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

---

Here is new dataset with month-quarter data

```
df <- structure(list(therapy_class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("ALK Inhibitors", 
"Anti-VEGF-based therapies", "EGFR TKIs", "EGFR-antibody based therapies", 
"Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "IO-based therapies", 
"Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "Single agent chemotherapies", 
"Other"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), quarter = structure(c(2020.75, 
2021, 2021.25, 2020.5, 2020.75, 2021.25, 2020.5, 2020.75, 2021, 
2021.25, NA, NA, 2020.5, 2020.75, 2021, 2021.25, 2021.5, 2020.5, 
2020.75, 2021, 2021.25, 2021.5, 2020.5, 2020.75, 2021, 2021.25, 
2021.5, 2020.5, 2020.75, 2021, 2021.25, 2021.5), class = "yearqtr"), 
    count = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
    252L, 184L, 190L, 180L, 120L, 59L, 46L, 63L, 47L, 25L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 21L, 21L, 11L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), groups = structure(list(therapy_class = structure(1:9, .Label = c("ALK Inhibitors", 
"Anti-VEGF-based therapies", "EGFR TKIs", "EGFR-antibody based therapies", 
"Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "IO-based therapies", 
"Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations", "Single agent chemotherapies", 
"Other"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = structure(list(
    1:3, 4:6, 7:10, 11L, 12L, 13:17, 18:22, 23:27, 28:32), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

--
The Quarter dates are out of order due to missing data

```
therapy_class                                `2020 Q4`      `2021 Q1`      `2021 Q2`      `2020 Q3`       `NA` `2021 Q3`     
   <ord>                                        <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <int> <chr>         
 1 ALK Inhibitors                               "4 [1.58%]"    "2 [0.72%]"    "2 [0.78%]"    ""                NA ""            
 2 Anti-VEGF-based therapies                    "2 [0.79%]"    ""             "3 [1.17%]"    "3 [0.90%]"       NA ""            
 3 EGFR TKIs                                    "1 [0.40%]"    "1 [0.36%]"    "1 [0.39%]"    "1 [0.30%]"       NA ""            
 4 EGFR-antibody based therapies                ""             ""             ""             ""                NA ""            
 5 Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations ""             ""             ""             ""                NA ""            
 6 IO-based therapies                           "184 [72.73%]" "190 [68.35%]" "180 [70.31%]" "252 [75.22%]"    NA "120 [76.43%]"
 7 Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations     "46 [18.18%]"  "63 [22.66%]"  "47 [18.36%]"  "59 [17.61%]"     NA "25 [15.92%]" 
 8 Single agent chemotherapies                  "4 [1.58%]"    "1 [0.36%]"    "2 [0.78%]"    "4 [1.19%]"       NA "1 [0.64%]"   
 9 Other                                        "12 [4.74%]"   "21 [7.55%]"   "21 [8.20%]"   "16 [4.78%]"      NA "11 [7.01%]"  
10 Total                                        "253"          "278"          "256"          "335"              0 "157"
```

Comment: There are no issues in your solution. I just have a new problem that is related. I am trying to do the same thing but instead of year-month I have quarterly data. Now it's again out of order. I am trying to create sequence of quarter from min to max and use complete function but that did not work

Comment: Try the solution in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create the missing year months with `complete` before doing the `pivot_wider`.  With `pivot_wider`, the default order is based on the unique value appearance in the order

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
df_2 %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(Year_month = as.Date(Year_month)) %>% 
    complete(therapy_class, Year_month =  seq(from = min(Year_month, 
     na.rm = TRUE), to = max(Year_month, na.rm = TRUE),
       by = '1 month')) %>% 
    mutate(Year_month = as.yearmon(Year_month)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
   mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("20")),
     list(
    ~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", paste(., sprintf("<br>[%1.1f%%]",
     100 * (. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))))
  ))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 8
  therapy_class                                `Dec 2019`        `Jan 2020`        `Feb 2020`        `Mar 2020`        `Apr 2020`     `May 2020`     `NA`
  <ord>                                        <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>          <chr>         <int>
1 ALK Inhibitors                               "16 <br>[2.7%]"   ""                "14 <br>[2.2%]"   "22 <br>[3.3%]"   "13 <br>[2.1%… "17 <br>[3.4…    NA
2 Anti-VEGF-based therapies                    "33 <br>[5.6%]"   "35 <br>[5.0%]"   "36 <br>[5.7%]"   "20 <br>[3.0%]"   "21 <br>[3.4%… "20 <br>[4.0…    NA
3 EGFR TKIs                                    "52 <br>[8.8%]"   "57 <br>[8.2%]"   "60 <br>[9.5%]"   "52 <br>[7.8%]"   "56 <br>[9.2%… "49 <br>[9.8…    NA
4 EGFR-antibody based therapies                ""                ""                ""                ""                ""             ""               NA
5 Non-platinum-based chemotherapy combinations "1 <br>[0.2%]"    "4 <br>[0.6%]"    "4 <br>[0.6%]"    ""                "1 <br>[0.2%]" ""               NA
6 IO-based therapies                           "308 <br>[52.0%]" "385 <br>[55.1%]" "330 <br>[52.3%]" "379 <br>[56.7%]" "345 <br>[56.… "265 <br>[52…    NA
7 Platinum-based chemotherapy combinations     "123 <br>[20.8%]" "147 <br>[21.0%]" "128 <br>[20.3%]" "134 <br>[20.1%]" "120 <br>[19.… "107 <br>[21…    NA
8 Single agent chemotherapies                  "29 <br>[4.9%]"   "33 <br>[4.7%]"   "17 <br>[2.7%]"   "28 <br>[4.2%]"   "25 <br>[4.1%… "22 <br>[4.4…    NA
9 Other                                        "30 <br>[5.1%]"   "38 <br>[5.4%]"   "42 <br>[6.7%]"   "33 <br>[4.9%]"   "31 <br>[5.1%… "21 <br>[4.2…    NA
```

---

With the new data

```
df %>% 
 ungroup %>% 
 mutate(Year_month = as.Date(quarter)) %>% 
 complete(therapy_class, 
  Year_month = seq(from = min(Year_month,na.rm = TRUE ), 
   to = max(Year_month, na.rm = TRUE), by = '1 quarter')) %>% 
  mutate(Year_month = as.yearqtr(Year_month))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%  
  ungroup() %>%   
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("20")), 
      list(     ~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", 
    paste(., sprintf("<br>[%1.1f%%]",   
     100 * (. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))))   ))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 35 × 8
   therapy_class             quarter   `2020 Q3`      `2020 Q4`      `2021 Q1`      `2021 Q2`      `2021 Q3`  `NA`
   <ord>                     <yearqtr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>     <int>
 1 ALK Inhibitors            <NA>      ""             ""             ""             ""             ""           NA
 2 ALK Inhibitors            2020 Q4   ""             "4 <br>[1.6%]" ""             ""             ""           NA
 3 ALK Inhibitors            2021 Q1   ""             ""             "2 <br>[0.7%]" ""             ""           NA
 4 ALK Inhibitors            2021 Q2   ""             ""             ""             "2 <br>[0.8%]" ""           NA
 5 Anti-VEGF-based therapies 2020 Q3   "3 <br>[0.9%]" ""             ""             ""             ""           NA
 6 Anti-VEGF-based therapies 2020 Q4   ""             "2 <br>[0.8%]" ""             ""             ""           NA
 7 Anti-VEGF-based therapies <NA>      ""             ""             ""             ""             ""           NA
 8 Anti-VEGF-based therapies 2021 Q2   ""             ""             ""             "3 <br>[1.2%]" ""           NA
 9 EGFR TKIs                 2020 Q3   "1 <br>[0.3%]" ""             ""             ""             ""           NA
10 EGFR TKIs                 2020 Q4   ""             "1 <br>[0.4%]" ""             ""             ""           NA
# … with 25 more rows
```

Comment: I have similar data set but instead of month and year I have Year and Quarter. I am not able to create the sequence of Quarters like you showed @akrun

Comment: @utsabshrestha that would be a different case  because you have quarters and probably there are duplicates.  The solution is based on the example data structure you provided

Comment: I have added the dataset with quarter month column. I tried doing this:
df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(quarter =  seq(from = min(quarter, na.rm = TRUE), 
                          to = max(quarter, na.rm = TRUE), 
                          by = '1 quarter'))
@akrun

Comment: @utsabshrestha try `df %>% ungroup %>% mutate(Year_month = as.Date(quarter)) %>% complete(therapy_class, Year_month = seq(from = min(Year_month,na.rm = TRUE ), to = max(Year_month, na.rm = TRUE), by = '1 quarter')) %>% mutate(Year_month = as.yearqtr(Year_month))  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%  ungroup() %>%
   mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("20")),
     list(
    ~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", paste(., sprintf("<br>[%1.1f%%]",
     100 * (. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))))
  ))`

Comment: I updated the post.  Tell me where it is having problems

Comment: Worked now :) Thanks